# why my downloaded file is 0 bytes

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, process

```
public string GetFilesToMyTemp(string target, FtpWebRequest ftpClient, BBSDbOperations _DbOperations, BBSFtpClient _BBSFtpType)
    {
        FileStream outputStream = null;
        FtpWebResponse response = null;
        Stream ftpStream = null;
        lock (locker)
        {
            try
            {

                using (outputStream = new FileStream(target, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    ftpClient.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
                    ftpClient.UseBinary = true;
                    ftpClient.KeepAlive = false;
                    ftpClient.UsePassive = true;
                    response = (FtpWebResponse)ftpClient.GetResponse();

                    ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

                    int bufferSize = 2048;

                    int readCount;

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    while (readCount > 0)
                    {
                        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                        readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    }
                }
                return "1";
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                String status = ((FtpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
                SetIstasyonBilgileriExceptions(_BBSFtpType, e.Message + "-" + status, DateTime.Now, "GetFilesToMyTemp");
                _DbOperations.InsertExceptionsLogs(_BBSFtpType);
                return "0";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //_DbOperations.Logla(_BBSFtpType, "c");
                SetIstasyonBilgileriExceptions(_BBSFtpType, ex.Message, DateTime.Now, "GetFilesToMyTemp");
                _DbOperations.InsertExceptionsLogs(_BBSFtpType);
                return "0";
            }
            finally
            {
                ftpStream.Close();
                ftpStream.Dispose();
                outputStream.Close();
                outputStream.Dispose();
                response.Close();
                response.Dispose();

            }
        }
    }
```

I use this method to download a file which is in ftp server to a local directory.This application is multithreaded. I have totally 550 files, 10 files from these files seems to be 0 bytes in local directory. How can I achieve this problem?

Comment: This is not about `java`, but in any way, I feel, you have to invoke `.flush()` on `outputstream` before closing it

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `outputStream.Flush();` before closing the stream.

Comment: When I added that outpıtStream.Flush(), I will get error Cannot access a closed file.

Comment: @user3894737 Because you should invoke it **BEFORE** closing outputstream, after loop end.

Comment: Ok I did it but again 0 bytes. I think may be it is related to multithreading.

Comment: Is there anybody tp help?